# Why do proper USB-C splitters not exist? [RETRY]

Tags: usb, power, splitters, usb-c

I need a USB-C splitter to connect my power adapter and an external SSD drive to my laptop, which has a single USB-C port, used for power input.

---

**To the moderators** - This is the copy of a previous post which has been canceled because "off-topic". I am looking around for a USB-C splitter to buy, and not asking to troubleshoot hardware or technical support for hardware. What follow are technical details about what I need and what I found on the market so far. Please, let me know if this is good enough or if I need other changes to comply with this forum requirements. Thank you.

---

What I could find so far are products which are designed for mobile phones (e.g. Belkin USB-C Splitter), which do not support the power requirements and bandwidth I need.

I understand you cannot get data from two USB-C inputs and make them flow into a signle USB-C output, but this is true only if the sum of the input data flows is larger than what the interface can handle.

I know you can connect devices with a serial topology, but you can do it only if the devices have two USB-C ports, which is rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no USB-C splitter come out this year because there is not single produced chipset for USB-C Splitter/Hub.

And if your laptop using USB-C for charging input there, the data pin is locked automatically because it was for reading voltage and making it to lock the pin for setting data input or voltage input in charging mode.

Explanation in USB-C pin:[image: Click here]
From:[medium.com](https://medium.com/@leung.benson/usb-type-c-s-configuration-channel-31e08047677d)

The CC2 port basically detecting the port whether it is for charging input or drawing power from it for the OTG/connected device..

You can try to draw and connect the USB2.0 interface but I will not do it while charging :) is too risky for precious SSD. Use a cheap USB 2.0 Flashdisk if it works then you can do it for your SSD but your SSD will be downgraded to USB 2.0 Speed. for using 2.0 interface.

PS: the risk worth your laptop or SSD. choose wisely :)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Can you please confirm whether it is technically possible to have USB-C splitters/hubs on the market in the future (and not with USB 2.0 performance), or if the underneeth technology does not allow it altoghether?

Comment: the technology does allow it. but the chipset should be manufactured by right now in 2021 could be take longer (assuming in 2020 the manufacturer hold this project all year)